# Max of multiple variables

Tags: excel, max, vba

I am trying to determine the max of 2 or 3 different variables (variants).
They are all dates.

```
Dim QA As Integer: QA = 0
For Each j_WS In Array(WS_1, WS_2, WS3)

    Select Case QA
        Case 0: j = 1
        Case 1: j = 2
        Case 2: j = 3
    End Select

    o = 14 + j * 3

    Dim WA1 As Variant
    Dim WA2 As Variant
    Dim WA3 As Variant
    Gorev = Cells(p, o).Address
    SlideNo = Cells(p, 34).Address
    Egitim_Adi = Cells(2, 3).Address
    Dim Satir_bul As Long

    Satir_bul = Worksheets(WS_All).Evaluate("=Match(" & Egitim_Adi & "&" & SlideNo & "&" & Gorev & ", '" & j_WS & "'!A:A&'" & j_WS & "'!B:B&'" & j_WS & "'!C:C, 0)")

    If j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Yeni Egitim" Or j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Tanitim / Reklam" Then
        WA1 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 7).Value
    Else: WA1 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 9).Value
        If j = 2 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Yeni Egitim" Or j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Tanitim / Reklam" Then
            WA2 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 7).Value
        Else: WA2 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 9).Value
            If j = 3 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Yeni Egitim" Or j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Tanitim / Reklam" Then
                WA3 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 7).Value
            Else: WA3 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 9).Value

            End If
        End If
    End If

    QA = QA + 1
Next j_WS

If WS_3 = "" And WS_2 = "" And WA1 <> "" Then
    Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(p, 26).Value = WA1

    If WS_3 = "" And WS_2 <> "" And WA1 <> "" And WA2 <> "" Then
        MAX_BITIS1 = WorksheetFunction.Max(WA1, WA2)
        Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(p, 26).Value = MAX_BITIS1

        If WA1 <> "" And WA2 <> "" And WA3 <> "" Then
            MAX_BITIS2 = WorksheetFunction.Max(WA1, WA2, WA3)
            Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(p, 26).Value = MAX_BITIS2
        Else
            Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(p, 26).Value = ""
        End If

    End If

End If
```

Almost everything is a predefined integer or something like that and WA1, WA2 and WA3 are all dates.

I want MAX_BITIS and MAX_BITIS2 to be dates too.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about `IF` conditions. What are `WS_3` and `WS_2`? If your first condition is satisfied with `WS_2 = ""` then none of following `IF` conditions will be executed beacuse of `WS_2 <> ""` in second `IF`. Also, can `ELSEIF` be helpful?

Comment: Well the If functions are about if there is a value in the WS_2 or 3 and if WA1, WA2 or WA3 are also have a value. Right now for testing both first and second conditions are met in the workbook ( I checked it with F8 ), but I cannot have the MAX_BITIS1. Also, with only meeting the second If function, I still cannot have a MAX_BITIS1.

Comment: If first and second `IF` conditions are satisfied, what exactly is the problem you are facing for calculating `MAX_BITIS1`?

Comment: Even though the if conditions are satisfied, MAX_BITIS1 doesn't bring me the max of WA1 and WA2.  Both WS_1, WS_2, WS_3, WA1, WA2 and WA3 are defined and I want to find the max of WA1, WA2 and/or WA3. I updated the codes to add before these parts to make it clear.

Comment: What does `MAX_BITIS1 = WorksheetFunction.Max(WA1, WA2)` results in, an error, wrong value or no value? Also, there is `For` loop missing for `Next j_WS`

Comment: Actually it gives no value. Next j_WS is down below in the codes. The loops are longer than this. But MAX_BITIS1 and 2 parts are only in here.

Comment: @Bildircin13 I had a similar problem some days ago. Try to convert to Var with `CVar` to use the function and then use `CDate` to convert back to Date